# Is it possible to upload data to read only bucket on amazon s3 using java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-s3

The bucket is in this region: null. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: 437E211C5EDD014D)

This Exception occurs when i tried to upload objects to amazon s3 bucket using java sdk using IAM user account aacess key and secret key.
I have only read access to the bucket and one object inside the bucket named xyz.
All permissions i do have is full access inside the xyz object.
Please help!

Comment: Which region do you have configured in your S3 client object? Try it with `us-east-1` (which is the default region). Could you show us your code?

Comment: public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3Conn(String accessKey, String secretKey) {
  BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
  return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build();
 },       I had tried it with all the regions one by one including us-east-1 , but still i am getting this exception